# excel - hyperlink to different workbook and specific worksheet?

Tags: excel

Using excel 2007. Trying to find the best way to hyperlink to a different workbook but also to a specific worksheet in that work book? Ive had a look at some suggestions but they are all using macros. Is there any other option i can try that doesnt involve macros?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put this in any cell as a formula

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\Book2.xlsm]Sheet3!B4","CLICK HERE")
```

This will navigate to

Workbook - C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\Book2.xlsm

Sheet - Sheet3

Cell - B4

Answer (score 7):

No need to use a formula - when searching for this information myself I found an easier way - use the usual hyperlink dialogue box and select the file but before doubleclicking it to create the hyperlink, click the 'bookmark' button (on the right in the dialogue box) - this opens to show you a list of all the sheets in the selected file so you can choose what sheet to link to. easy!

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what i was looking for.