# Link to a specific tab in a different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I need a button or hyperlink in Excel to open on a specific tab in a different workbook.

I already know how to make a hyperlink to link to a different workbook.... but not open it on a specific tab.

Comment: =HYPERLINK("[C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\Book2.xlsm]Sheet3!B4","CLICK HERE")
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807556/excel-hyperlink-to-different-workbook-and-specific-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

As this was a VBA question, you would need to qualify the **SubAddress** parameter of the [Hyperlinks.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx).

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("C3"), Address:= _
    environ("APPDATA") & Chr(92) & "MyWorkbook.xlsb", _
    SubAddress:="Sheet2", _
    TextToDisplay:="Go to Sheet2 in MyWorkbook"
```

That will put a hyperlink into the current workbook's active worksheet's C3 cell. The displayed text is *'Go to Sheet2 in MyWorkbook'* and clicking on it will go to Sheet2 in the external workbook (somewhere in your user profile's APPDATA folder).